# Problem with \newcommand, no space after calling new command in the compiled text

Tags: macros, spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\newcommand and spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17730/newcommand-and-spacing)

In my latex document I have defined a new command to force a consistency in naming of a product I talk in my document:

```
\newcommand{\fancyName}{\emph{ABC}}
```

However I experience a problem that:

```
\fancyName is a wonderfull and fancy product.
```

is compiled to:

```
ABCis a wonderfull and fancy product.
```

without a space after \fancyName in the compiled text.

Does anybody know how to define a new command and avoid this issue?

Comment: guess it is a dublicate

Comment: (La)TeX ignores all spaces after any macro, user defined or not. This is because the space might just be a separator to indicate the end of the macro name. As already states in the answer here and in the duplicate question: Either use `{}` after the macro, insert an explicit space using `\ `, `~` (unbreakable), or `\space` or add `\xspace` at the very end. It will add a space if the macro isn't used before a punctuation mark.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a well known "problem". You can either write     \macro{}
or maybe you consider using

```
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\fancyName}{\emph{ABC}\xspace}
```

xspace should create a space if the macro is used in text but no space if it is at the end of a sentence and followed by a full stop.

Comment: Another option is to add `{}` after the macro call, like `\fancyName{}`.