# Get current "section" name without label

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir

**Update:**

I accepted the solution provided by [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek), because that was doing exactly what I asked.

When interested only in the chapter name, [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s solution works fine. However, to get it working with memoir, one has to change the parameter from `#1` to `#2`. Don't ask me why.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\gdef\currentchapter{#2}}{}{}
\def\currentchapter{?}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
``\currentchapter''
\section{A Section}
``\currentchapter''
\end{document}
```

**Old question:**
I want to get the name of the current "section" (chapter, section, subsection, ...) *without* labeling the section.

I tried using `\nameref` with e.g. `\thechapter` which obviously doesn't work, as `\nameref` expects a reference (the name of `\label`) and not a number.

Is there a command, that gives me directly the name of the current "section"? Or is there a command which can "generate" a reference out of section numbering, like: `\getname{\thechapter}`?

I found out already, that it is impossible to get the numbering of the current "section" - I'd need to check the counter to get the correct "section".

My goal is to redefine `\todo` from the package [`todonotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) that it always displays the current "section" name:

```
\let\Oldtodo\todo
\renewcommand{\todo}[1]{\Oldtodo{\currentname: #1}}
```

If it is not possible to get the name of the current "section", I would be happy with the current chapter or section name too:

```
\let\Oldtodo\todo
\renewcommand{\todo}[1]{\Oldtodo{\currentchaptername: #1}}
```

Below is a simple example without `todonotes`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\section{My section name}
The name of the current section is: " \currentname "
It should be: " My section name "

\subsection{My subsection name}
The name of the current subsection is: " \currentname "
It should be: " My subsection name "

\end{document}
```

Notice that I'm using documentclass memoir.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What's is the intention of your question? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I added my intent and some examples including a MWE.

Comment: To my current knowledge, it is only possible to use `nameref` in combinations with `labels`. Is there some other way? Like receiving a reference from header numbering? This way, one could get the reference and plug it into `nameref`: `\nameref{\getrefofnumber{\thechapter}}`

Comment: Very naively, is `The name of the current section is: "\rightmark"` doing what you would like? This is what is used (at least in memoir) to extract the name of the current section and put it in the headers. Note that, as section numbering is also given in headers, you might be able to find a way to extract it too if you make some digging in this direction.

Comment: I'm using memoir too, but in my document, \rightmark contains the section before the current section...

Comment: @r0estir0bbe Of course it works out of the box with `\currenttitle` instead of `\currentname`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Variations of the same theme. All the `title`-/`nameref` packages have to remember the current title somewhere.

### Package `nameref`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{My section name}
The name of the current section is: "\currentname".\\
It should be: "My section name".

\subsection{My subsection name}
The name of the current subsection is: "\currentname".\\
It should be: "My subsection name".

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with nameref]

### Package `titleref`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titleref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\TR@currentTitle}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{My section name}
The name of the current section is: "\currentname".\\
It should be: "My section name".

\subsection{My subsection name}
The name of the current subsection is: "\currentname".\\
It should be: "My subsection name".

\end{document}
```

Same result.

### Package `zref-titleref`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-titleref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\zref@getcurrent{title}}
% or \newcommand*{\currentname}{\zref@titleref@current}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{My section name}
The name of the current section is: "\currentname".\\
It should be: "My section name".

\subsection{My subsection name}
The name of the current subsection is: "\currentname".\\
It should be: "My subsection name".

\end{document}
```

Same result.

Comment: Can you add a comment on how to prevent `\currentname` from eating of the consecutive space?

Comment: @Lukas: See the [comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/problem-with-newcommand-no-space-after-calling-new-command-in-the-compiled-tex#comment33338_17872) of Martin Scharrer for the question ["Problem with \newcommand, no space after calling new command in the compiled text "](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17872/16967).

Comment: @Lukas: See also question ["Space after LaTeX commands"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Yes, that solved it. Thank you.

Comment: Any better solution for this? I mean when I use nameref It uses 10GB of RAM (Lualatex) and I have to kill it.

Comment: @Kyslik The answer contains *three* solutions. All of them can be used with LuaLaTeX. None of the examples require 10GB of RAM. Post a new question with a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that can be analyzed to find the real nature of the problem.

Comment: The first two solutions do not work on the last page of the bibliography or table of contents anymore. I show the current chapter/section name in the footer. On the last page however it shows the name of the previous chapter?!

Comment: @user2656284 The first two solutions probably need numbered chapters/sections.

Comment: `titleref` does not work with beamer, but `zref-titleref` works great!

Answer (score 48):

Not exactly an answer to your question but maybe useful to others:

The [Beamer class](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer) provides the commands `\secname` and `\subsecname` to get the current sections or subsections name.

This example produces a frame containing the text "Current section: Foo":

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \section{Foo}
  \begin{frame}
    Current section: \secname
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can this also be used in templates? I want to include the current section name in the frame title, but including it with `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\secname}` does not work. I figure it has something to do with the order of when which macro is expanded?

Comment: This post comes up when searching for how to do exactly this in beamer, so yes, it is useful.

Comment: Truly, it is useful to others. I would even give this example: `begin{frame}{\secname}` . I use the name of the section to set the title of the current frame. You can go further, if you use the subsection as subtitle ;) `begin{frame}{\secname}{\subsecname}`

Answer (score 17):

If you use the standard classes that rely on the kernel commands for making headers, then here's a possibility that works unmodified if the class is `article` (removing the `\chapter` command, of course).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@chapters
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\@chaptersfalse}{\@chapterstrue}
\if@chapters
  \apptocmd{\@chapter}{\gdef\currentname{#1}}{}{}
  \apptocmd{\@schapter}{\gdef\currentname{#1}}{}{}
\fi
\apptocmd{\@sect}{\gdef\currentname{#7}}{}{}
\def\currentname{---Still no title given---}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{ABC}

\currentname

\section{My section name}
The name of the current section is: ``\currentname''
It should be: ``My section name''

\subsection{My subsection name}
The name of the current subsection is: ``\currentname''
It should be: ``My subsection name''

\end{document}
```

For the `memoir` class there's nothing to do: the class already provides `\currenttitle` that does *exactly* what you want.

---

Note that you shouldn't redefine `\todo` as you're trying; rather do

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\todo[2][]{\@todo[#1]{\currentname: #2}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: When trying to compile your MWE, I get the following error:
`> \@chapter=macro: [...]
l.11 \show\@chapter`
Commenting the line `\show\@chapter` solves the compilation error, but I don't know if it breaks something in your idea.

Comment: @r0estir0bbe Sorry, that was only for debugging. I'll remove it.

Comment: I tried your solution in my main document and I didn't work. Then I realized, that I'm using class memoir. Apparently, this breaks your solution. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @r0estir0bbe `memoir` provides `\currenttitle`

Comment: Maybe useful to others: make sure to load ``etoolbox`` before ``bookmark``, ``hyperref`` and such. Otherwise errors may pop up: e.g., ``! Use of \Hy@org@chapter doesn't match its definition.
\NR@chapter ...\fi \Hy@next \Hy@org@chapter \gdef``.

Answer (score 8):

You could do something like

```
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[2][]{\def\currentname{#2}\oldsection[#1]{#2}}
```

You probably would want to deal with optional arguments to sectioning commands in a better way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\oldsection\section
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\section}[2][]{\def\currentname{#2}\oldsection[#1]{#2}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}[2][]{\def\currentname{#2}\oldsubsection[#1]{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{My section name}
The name of the current section is: " \currentname "
It should be: " My section name "

\subsection{My subsection name}
The name of the current subsection is: " \currentname "
It should be: " My subsection name "

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with: _You probably would want to deal with optional arguments to sectioning commands in a better way_?

Comment: @r0estir0bbe I mean that the command is not perfect. If you look at what gets written in the `toc` file you will see it gets screwed up since I pass the sectioning commands an empty optional argument. An empty optional argument is not the same as no optional argument.  It also doesn't handle the `*` form of sectioning commands at all (and hence breaks `\tableofcontents`). I think fixing these things would be relatively easy, but is unrelated to the question asked.

Comment: Well, it is true that your example breaks `*` commands. I tried to find some guides on how to redefine a section command, but I wasn't really successful. Do you know a "How To" for redefining section commands or similar?