# Use section title in running head of Latex KOMA presentation script

Tags: koma-script, templates, presentations

I would like to use the Latex KOMA presentation template [1] for my presentation.
But I want to replace the *running head* at the top by the (sub)section title.

Currently the Latex KOMA presentation template [1] looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[
paper=128mm:96mm, % The same paper size as used in the beamer class
fontsize=11pt, % Font size
pagesize, % Write page size to dvi or pdf
parskip=half-, % Paragraphs separated by half a line
]{scrartcl} % KOMA script (article)

\linespread{1.12} % Increase line spacing for readability

%------------------------------------------------
% Colors
\usepackage{xcolor}  % Required for custom colors
% Define a few colors for making text stand out within the presentation
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{44,85,17}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{34,31,217}
\definecolor{mybrown}{RGB}{194,164,113}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{255,66,56}
% Use these colors within the presentation by enclosing text in the commands below
\newcommand*{\mygreen}[1]{\textcolor{mygreen}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\myblue}[1]{\textcolor{myblue}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mybrown}[1]{\textcolor{mybrown}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\myred}[1]{\textcolor{myred}{#1}}
%------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------
% Margins
\usepackage[ % Page margins settings
includeheadfoot,
top=3.5mm,
bottom=3.5mm,
left=5.5mm,
right=5.5mm,
headsep=6.5mm,
footskip=8.5mm
]{geometry}
%------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------
% Fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     % For correct hyphenation and T1 encoding
\usepackage{lmodern} % Default font: latin modern font
%\usepackage{fourier} % Alternative font: utopia
%\usepackage{charter} % Alternative font: low-resolution roman font
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Sans serif - this may need to be commented to see the alternative fonts
%------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------
% Various required packages
\usepackage{amsthm} % Required for theorem environments
\usepackage{bm} % Required for bold math symbols (used in the footer of the slides)
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images in figures
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for colored boxes
\usepackage{booktabs} % Required for horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{multicol} % Required for creating multiple columns in slides
\usepackage{lastpage} % For printing the total number of pages at the bottom of each slide
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Document language - required for customizing section titles
\usepackage{microtype} % Better typography
\usepackage{tocstyle} % Required for customizing the table of contents
%------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------
% Slide layout configuration
\usepackage{scrpage2} % Required for customization of the header and footer
\pagestyle{scrheadings} % Activates the pagestyle from scrpage2 for custom headers and footers
\clearscrheadfoot % Remove the default header and footer
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\color{black}\sffamily} % Font settings for the header and footer

% Sets vertical centering of slide contents with increased space between paragraphs/lists
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@textbottom}{\vskip \z@ \@plus 1fil}
\newcommand*{\@texttop}{\vskip \z@ \@plus .5fil}
\addtolength{\parskip}{\z@\@plus .25fil}
\makeatother

% Remove page numbers and the dots leading to them from the outline slide
\makeatletter
\newtocstyle[noonewithdot]{nodotnopagenumber}{\settocfeature{pagenumberbox}{\@gobble}}
\makeatother
\usetocstyle{nodotnopagenumber}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcaptionname{english}{\contentsname}{\Large Outline}} % Change the name of the table of contents
%------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------
% Header configuration - if you don't want a header remove this block
\ihead{
\hspace{-2mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [xshift=\paperwidth/2,yshift=-\headheight] (mybar) at (current page.north west)[rectangle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=\paperwidth,minimum height=2\headheight,top color=mygreen!64,bottom color=mygreen]{}; % Colored bar
\node[below of=mybar,yshift=3.3mm,rectangle,shade,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=128mm,minimum height =1.5mm,top color=black!50,bottom color=white]{}; % Shadow under the colored bar
shadow
\end{tikzpicture}
\color{white}\runninghead} % Header text defined by the \runninghead command below and colored white for contrast
%------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------
% Footer configuration
%\newlength{\footheight}
\setlength{\footheight}{8mm} % Height of the footer
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\footnotesize} % Small font size for the footnote

\ifoot{% Left side
\hspace{-2mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [xshift=\paperwidth/2,yshift=\footheight] at (current page.south west)[rectangle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=\paperwidth,minimum height=3pt,top color=mygreen,bottom color=mygreen]{}; % Green bar
\end{tikzpicture}
\myauthor\ \raisebox{0.2mm}{$\bm{\vert}$}\ \myuni % Left side text
}

\ofoot[\pagemark/\pageref{LastPage}\hspace{-2mm}]{\pagemark/\pageref{LastPage}\hspace{-2mm}} % Right side
%------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------
% Section spacing - deeper section titles are given less space due to lesser importance
\usepackage{titlesec} % Required for customizing section spacing
\titlespacing{\section}{0mm}{0mm}{0mm} % Lengths are: left, before, after
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0mm}{0mm}{-1mm} % Lengths are: left, before, after
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0mm}{0mm}{-2mm} % Lengths are: left, before, after
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % How deep sections are numbered, set to no numbering by default - change to 1 for numbering sections, 2 for numbering sections and subsections, etc
%------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRESENTATION INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand*{\mytitle}{Presentation Title} % Title
\newcommand*{\runninghead}{Running Head} % Running head displayed on almost all slides
\newcommand*{\myauthor}{John Smith} % Presenters name(s)
\newcommand*{\mydate}{\today} % Presentation date
\newcommand*{\myuni}{University of California --- Department of Statistics} % University or department
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Displaying Text}
\clearpage
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have tried to replace the *running head* by the following custom `\currtitle` command:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\currtitle}{\ttl@savetitle}
\makeatother

%------------------------------------------------
% Header configuration - if you don't want a header remove this block
\ihead{
\hspace{-2mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [xshift=\paperwidth/2,yshift=-\headheight] (mybar) at (current page.north west)[rectangle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=\paperwidth,minimum height=2\headheight,top color=mygreen!64,bottom color=mygreen]{}; % Colored bar
\node[below of=mybar,yshift=3.3mm,rectangle,shade,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=128mm,minimum height =1.5mm,top color=black!50,bottom color=white]{}; % Shadow under the colored bar
shadow
\end{tikzpicture}
\color{white}\currtitle} % Header text defined by the \runninghead command below and colored white for contrast
```

[image]

But how can I hide the section title within the slide? (below the green header bar)
Or how can I move the (sub)section title to the *running head* position?

Thanks!

[1] http://www.latextemplates.com/template/koma-script-presentation

Comment: Please edit your question and add a minimal working example. And I don't get it: which kind of heading do you desire?

Comment: I've included a minimal working example in the question. I want to have the section title at the *running head* position at the top. So no *running head* at all, but the section or subsection title should appear within the green header bar.

Comment: [Get current "section" name without label](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75183)

Comment: The problem is not to get the current section name but to hide the actual `\section{Displaying Text}` output. The section name (e.g., "Displaying Text") should only appear in the green header bar.

Comment: @Martin Make sure to ping people by adding an At-sign (@) in front of their name.

Comment: Do you need a toc? If you don't it is quite simple and it suffices to do `\renewcommand{\runninghead}{your title}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B I don't want to have a fixed *running head* title. I want to have the current section title instead of a constant *running head*.

Comment: You can use `renewcommand`as often as you like. Do you need an automatically generated toc?

Comment: @Johannes_B You don't understand my problem. I would like to use the KOMA presentation template [1] but instead of a static *running head*, which is normally defined by `\newcommand*{\runninghead}{Running Head}`, I want to have the current section title within the green header bar at the top. Therefore I tried to use `\newcommand{\currtitle}{\ttl@savetitle}` within the header `\ihead{...\color{white}\currtitle}`, which prints the current section title within the green header bar at the top. But I also want to remove the section title within the slide (below the green header bar).

Comment: I understand the problem pretty well, but the question remains: *Do you need a generated TOC*?

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, I would like to generate a TOC by `\thispagestyle{empty} % No slide header and footer
\small\tableofcontents
\clearpage`

Comment: Would something like the following be enough? `\newcommand\sectiona[1]{%
\clearpage%
\refstepcounter{section}%
\renewcommand{\runninghead}{#1}%
\addsectiontocentry{}{#1}%
}`

Comment: @Johannes_B One last question. How can I define the commands `\sectiona*` and `\subsectiona`? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked you in the comments, if you need to genereate a TOC and
was pretty persistent with my request for an answer. There is a
pretty good reason for that.

Right now, (with this solution/workaround) there are no section
titles printed at all (in the classical sense using `\@startsection`). Everytime you call the new command `sectiona` the
page ist cleared (i.e. a new page/slide starting), the running
head is updated and a toc entry is created. One could just renew
the section definition, but that would mean messing up the
definition of `\tableofcontents`, and maybe a list of
figures/tables or a bibliography.

The orignal paper by Markus is
a few years old and many things changed. For example, KOMA now
initiates a huge warning because `titlesec` is used. A new
package called `scrlayer-scrpage` has joined the KOMA bundle
making a great contribution to the running head thing.

To sum it up, the article presented a prototype to use the
KOMA-article class for presentatins. There are some rough edges
that need to be polished. For a prototype, it was quite good a
few years ago, but right now, and especially in the provided
template, I would say: »Keep your hands off it!«

Back to topic, what did i do? I used package xparse to check for
a starred version. The starred version updates the running header
(which is something like a frametitle), but does not place a
toc-entry. Also, the counter of `section` (which isn't used
anyway) is advanced by one.
If you don't use the starred command of `sectiona`, you can
choose an optional title for the toc-entry. This is somehow
equivalent to the standard behaviour of the section command.
`subsectiona`s update the header, tough a bit smaller, and add a subsectionentry in the TOC.

DISCLAIMER: The template provided has some sharp edges,
especially if you think overlays and nifty stuff like that are
great, switch to a class that was designed to do this.
Don't get me wrong, using scrartcl for presentations is a great
idea, but you will never get all the bells and whistles that
`beamer` provides.

What is important to the MWE is just the following to be honest, not much, but still ...

```
\usepackage{xparse}
%
\DeclareDocumentCommand\sectiona{s o m}{%
    \clearpage%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \renewcommand{\runninghead}{#3}%
    }{%
        \refstepcounter{section}%JB: Please don't aske mw, %
%why i am doing this, as they aren't printed anyway%
        \renewcommand{\runninghead}{#3}%always use the%
%       mandatory argument for the runninghead%
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
            \addsectiontocentry{}{#3}%
        }{%
            \addsectiontocentry{}{#2}%
        }%
    }%
}%
\newcommand\subsectiona[1]{%
    \clearpage%
    \refstepcounter{subsection}%
    \renewcommand{\runninghead}{\small #1\par}%
    \addsubsectiontocentry{}{#1}%
}%
%
```

And now the full example, ready to copy/paste/compile:

```
\documentclass[
paper=128mm:96mm, 
fontsize=11pt, 
pagesize, 
parskip=half-, 
]{scrartcl} 

\linespread{1.12} 

\usepackage{bm}  
\usepackage{xcolor}  

\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{44,85,17}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{34,31,217}
\definecolor{mybrown}{RGB}{194,164,113}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{255,66,56}

\newcommand*{\mygreen}[1]{\textcolor{mygreen}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\myblue}[1]{\textcolor{myblue}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mybrown}[1]{\textcolor{mybrown}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\myred}[1]{\textcolor{myred}{#1}}




\usepackage[ 
includeheadfoot,
top=3.5mm,
bottom=3.5mm,
left=5.5mm,
right=5.5mm,
headsep=6.5mm,
footskip=8.5mm
]{geometry}




\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage{lmodern} 


\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 




\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{lastpage} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{tocstyle} 
\usepackage{scrpage2} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\clearscrheadfoot 
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\color{black}\sffamily} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@textbottom}{\vskip \z@ \@plus 1fil}
\newcommand*{\@texttop}{\vskip \z@ \@plus .5fil}
\addtolength{\parskip}{\z@\@plus .25fil}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newtocstyle[noonewithdot]{nodotnopagenumber}{\settocfeature{pagenumberbox}{\@gobble}}
\makeatother
\usetocstyle{nodotnopagenumber}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcaptionname{english}{\contentsname}{Outline}} 




\ihead{
\hspace{-2mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [xshift=\paperwidth/2,yshift=-\headheight] (mybar) at (current page.north west)[rectangle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=\paperwidth,minimum height=2\headheight,top color=mygreen!64,bottom color=mygreen]{}; 
\node[below of=mybar,yshift=3.3mm,rectangle,shade,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=128mm,minimum height =1.5mm,top color=black!50,bottom color=white]{}; 
shadow
\end{tikzpicture}
\color{white}\runninghead} 





\setlength{\footheight}{8mm} 
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\footnotesize} 

\ifoot{
\hspace{-2mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [xshift=\paperwidth/2,yshift=\footheight] at (current page.south west)[rectangle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=\paperwidth,minimum height=3pt,top color=mygreen,bottom color=mygreen]{}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\myauthor\ \raisebox{0.2mm}{$\bm{\vert}$}\ \myuni 
}

\ofoot[\pagemark/\pageref{LastPage}\hspace{-2mm}]{\pagemark/\pageref{LastPage}\hspace{-2mm}} 




\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titlespacing{\section}{0mm}{0mm}{0mm} 
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0mm}{0mm}{-1mm} 
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0mm}{0mm}{-2mm} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} 





\newcommand*{\mytitle}{Presentation Title} 
\usepackage{nameref}
\newcommand*{\runninghead}{}
\newcommand*{\myauthor}{John Smith} 
\newcommand*{\mydate}{\today} 
\newcommand*{\myuni}{University of California --- Department of Statistics} 


\usepackage{xparse}
%
\DeclareDocumentCommand\sectiona{s o m}{%
    \clearpage%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \renewcommand{\runninghead}{#3}%
    }{%
        \refstepcounter{section}%JB: Please don't aske mw, %
%why i am doing this, as they aren't printed anyway%
        \renewcommand{\runninghead}{#3}%always use the%
%       mandatory argument for the runninghead%
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
            \addsectiontocentry{}{#3}%
        }{%
            \addsectiontocentry{}{#2}%
        }%
    }%
}%
\newcommand\subsectiona[1]{%
    \clearpage%
    \refstepcounter{subsection}%
    \renewcommand{\runninghead}{\small #1\par}%
    \addsubsectiontocentry{}{#1}%
}%
%




\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\sectiona{a section}
Text in a section, runninghead updated

\sectiona{a different section}
Text in another section, runninghead updated
\subsectiona{a subsection}
The runninghead is now smaller, to distiguish it a bit from a
section
\sectiona*{a starred section}
Text in a starred section, runninghead updated, but no toc entry

\sectiona[toc entry]{running head}
an optional argument? REALLY?
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just saw that you want your toc-page `empty`. You can do it now using `this[agestyl{empty}`. Out of curiousity, is this what you want the page to look like? If not, i already mentioned package `scrlayer-scrpage`, capable of placing stuff at the background.