# How to add part title to headers in memoir

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, memoir

I want to add the unnumbered part title into the headers in memoir, but \thepart command produces only the part number without the title.  How would I redefine \thepart command to get the desired result?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{\textit{Book Title}}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\textit{\thepart}}{}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{\thepage}{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\part{Part Title}

\include{Chapter1}
\include{chapter2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the solutions proposed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75168/get-current-section-name-without-label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{\textit{Book Title}}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\rightmark}{}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{\thepage}{}
\clearmark{chapter}
\clearmark{section}
\createmark{part}{both}{shownumber}{\partname\space}{.\space}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part Title}

\chapter{Chapter1}
\lipsum[1-30]
\chapter{chapter2}
\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

The `memoir` trick is that you need to clear out the old marks using `\clearmark`, and then create a "mark" for the `\part`-level division.

Comment: Thanks for adding "the trick is that you need to clear out the old marks" with `\clearmark`. After reading documentation and other answers, it seems not at all clear to me that this would be necessary, especially when defining a brand new page style.