# \rightmark not displaying subsection

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

## Current situation

My document (`report`) consists of chapters, sections and subsections. Now I want to display the section name and the subsection name on the left side of the footer. However if I use `\rightmark` I only get the section name, not the subsection one too.

## A minimal example

I tried to reduce the problem to this minimal example which is basically the code from my actual document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

% <header_footer>
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
% </header_footer>

% ...
% a lot of other stuff here
% ...

% <toc>
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

    \newcommand\invisiblesection[1]{%
        \refstepcounter{section}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
        \sectionmark{#1}}

    \newcommand\invisiblesubsection[1]{%
        \refstepcounter{subsection}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
        \subsectionmark{#1}}
% </toc>

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \chapter{a chapter}
    \newpage

    \invisiblesection{section}
    \invisiblesubsection{subsection}
    content to ensure the page is there
    \newpage

    \invisiblesection{another section}
    \invisiblesubsection{subsection 1}
    content to ensure the page is there 
    % the header should now display "another section - subsection 1"
    \newpage

    \invisiblesubsection{subsection 2}
    content to ensure the page is there 
    % the header should now display "another section - subsection 2"
    \newpage

    \invisiblesubsection{subsection 3}
    content to ensure the page is there 
    % the header should now display "another section - subsection 3"
\end{document}
```

## What it looks like

[image: image displaying what it looks like]

## What it should look like

[image: image displaying what it should look like]

## What I tried so far

- overriding both marks - didn't work as the `\leftmark` was defined as the chapter's name
- getting the current section name with [`nameref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75168/get-current-section-name-without-label) - didn't work as it was fetching the chapter's name
- `\def`ining custom variables each time a `\invisiblesection` is created - didn't work either

## Question

I suppose there's just one dead simple flag which I forgot but google didn't tell me. Does anybody have a solution to display both the section and subsection name in a header/footer?

Comment: The default definition of `\subsectionmark` is “do nothing”.

Comment: Some more details are needed: do you always have a subsection starting after a section title? If not, what should the header display?

Comment: How would I go about appending something to the `\rightmark` then? I've read that only the first occurence of of it will be used. I updated the question to show how it's in the actual document.

Comment: Edited the code and added what it should look like.

Comment: The addition is quite unclear; you can typically have only the first subsection that starts in the current page in the header. Do you need chapter titles in the header or footer?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I missed the `\newpage` after each subsection's content. I edited it again, maybe it's better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\subsectionmark` command is defined to do nothing, so you need to change its definition if you want it issues a mark.

Similarly, you have to change `\sectionmark` so it *doesn't* issue a mark.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\newcommand\invisiblesection[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \sectionmark{#1}%
}

\newcommand\invisiblesubsection[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
  \subsectionmark{#1}%
}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \gdef\currsection{#1}%
}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{\currsection\ \textbullet\ #1}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\invisiblesection{section}
\invisiblesubsection{subsection}
content to ensure the page is there
\newpage

\invisiblesection{another section}
\invisiblesubsection{subsection 1}
content to ensure the page is there 
% the header should now display "another section - subsection 1"
\newpage

\invisiblesubsection{subsection 2}
content to ensure the page is there 
% the header should now display "another section - subsection 2"
\newpage

\invisiblesubsection{subsection 3}
content to ensure the page is there 
% the header should now display "another section - subsection 3"

\end{document}
```

Here's the top of page 4

[image]