# Refer to title of direct superior section in an inferior section

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

## General

I know there are question about "how to refer to a **specific** title" however I need a way to generally refer to the superior section's title or to the title of the current section of a specific level (similar to referring to a section's counter using `\thesection`).

My documentclass is `article`.

## Problem

I have a tree like document where the title of each section describes an element in the tree. The section titles should be the path to the corresponding element.

[image]

However I don't want to specify the full path to the element in the section command (`\subsubsection{A/B1/C}`) as this can cause a lot of refactoring work when an element in the path changes.
I would prefer to only specify the leaf element (the last or tail element) of the path while the head is automatically deduced from the superior section. Something like:

```
% How should \currentsectionname and \currentsubsectionname be defined?
\newcommand{\treesubsection}[1]{\subsection{\currentsectionname /#1}}
\newcommand{\treesubsubsection}[1]{\subsubsection{\currentsubsectionname /#1}}

\section{A}
\treesubsection{B1}
\treesubsubsection{C}
```

I tried the solutions from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75168/get-current-section-name-without-label) however they only seem to work when used within a section's body but not within the title:

- The `nameref` solution gives me `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]`.
- The `titleref` solution duplicates the leaf title (i.e. results in for example `A/B1/B1` instead of `A/B1`).
- The `zref-titleref` solution puts a "currentname" instead of the head and also duplicates the leaf.

## Question

How can I refer to the superior section's title or to the title of the current section of a specific level, similar to `\thesection`, `\thesubsection`, ... ?
In addition I want to use the feature that I can choose a custom section title for the TOC, as it is possible for `\section[custom toc title]{title}`. Actually the custom title should always be the leaf name.

## EDIT (what I tried specifically)

### nameref

```
\usepackage{nameref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\treesubsection}[1]{\subsection{\currentname /#1}}
\newcommand{\treesubsubsection}[1]{\subsubsection{\currentname /#1}}
```

### titleref

```
\usepackage{titleref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\TR@currentTitle}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\treesubsection}[1]{\subsection{\currentname /#1}}
\newcommand{\treesubsubsection}[1]{\subsubsection{\currentname /#1}}
```

### zref-titleref

```
\usepackage{zref-titleref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\zref@getcurrent{title}}
% \newcommand*{\currentname}{\zref@titleref@current}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\treesubsection}[1]{\subsection{\currentname /#1}}
\newcommand{\treesubsubsection}[1]{\subsubsection{\currentname /#1}}
```

Comment: Please provide at least a version of your document that has this structure and show what you have tried with `nameref` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\newcommand{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}` has no effect. It would refer to the current value of `\@currentlabelname` or is even undefined. In fact, the `\@currentlabelname` must be stored in an expansion step to another macro **after** the section title has been set, not in the argument.

Please note that the current definition of `\tree...` misses the possibility of using `\treesection[short toc title]{long title}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\treesection}[1]{\section{#1}
 \edef\currentsectionname{\@currentlabelname}}

\newcommand{\treesubsection}[1]{\subsection{\currentsectionname/#1}\edef\currentsubsectionname{\@currentlabelname}}
\newcommand{\treesubsubsection}[1]{\subsubsection{\currentsubsectionname /#1}\edef\currentsubsubsectionname{\@currentlabelname}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\treesection{A}
\treesubsection{B1}
\treesubsection{B2}
\treesubsubsection{C1}


\treesection{Z}
\treesubsection{B1}
\treesubsection{B2}
\treesubsubsection{C1}


\end{document}
```

**Update** 'Automatic' definition of a `tree level` and declaration of the `\current...name` with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{nameref}

\usepackage{xparse}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineTreeLevel}{om}{%
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname tree#2\endcsname{som}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{##1}{%
      \csname #2*\endcsname{##3}
    }{%
      \def\@@tempa@@{}%
      \IfValueT{#1}{%
        \def\@@tempa@@{\csname current#1name\endcsname/}
      }
      \IfValueTF{##2}{%
        \csname #2\endcsname[##2]{\@@tempa@@##3}%
      }{%
        \csname #2\endcsname{\@@tempa@@##3}%
      }%
      \expandafter\edef\csname current#2name\endcsname{\@currentlabelname}%
    }%
  }%
}

\makeatother


\DefineTreeLevel{chapter}
\DefineTreeLevel[chapter]{section}
\DefineTreeLevel[section]{subsection}
\DefineTreeLevel[subsection]{subsubsection}


\begin{document}

\treechapter{Gamma}
\treesection{A1}
\treesubsection{B1}
\treesubsection{B2}
\treesubsubsection{C1}


\treesection{Z}
\treesubsection{B1}
\treesubsection{B2}
\treesubsubsection{C1}


\end{document}
```

**Update**

ToC - related stuff with some screenshot

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\usepackage{xparse}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineTreeLevel}{om}{%
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname tree#2\endcsname{som}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{##1}{%
      \csname #2*\endcsname{##3}
    }{%
      \def\@@tempa@@{}%
      \IfValueT{#1}{%
        \def\@@tempa@@{\csname current#1name\endcsname/}
      }
      \IfValueTF{##2}{%
        \csname #2\endcsname[##2]{\@@tempa@@##3}%
      }{%
        \csname #2\endcsname{\@@tempa@@##3}%
      }%
      \expandafter\edef\csname current#2name\endcsname{\@currentlabelname}%
    }%
  }%
}

\makeatother


\DefineTreeLevel{section}
\DefineTreeLevel[section]{subsection}
\DefineTreeLevel[subsection]{subsubsection}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\treesection{A1}
\treesubsection[B1]{B1}
\treesubsection{B2}
\treesubsubsection[C1]{C1}


\treesection{Z}
\treesubsection{B1}
\treesubsection{B2}
\treesubsubsection{C1}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Next update**, recursive `\@current....` names:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\usepackage{xparse}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineTreeLevel}{om}{%
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname tree#2\endcsname{som}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{##1}{%
      \csname #2*\endcsname{##3}%
    }{%
      \gdef\@@tempa@@{}%
      \IfValueT{#1}{%
        \def\@@tempa@@{\csname current#1name\endcsname/}
      }%
      \IfValueTF{##2}{%
        \csname #2\endcsname[##2]{\@@tempa@@##3}%
        \expandafter\edef\csname current#2name\endcsname{\@@tempa@@\@currentlabelname}%
      }{%
        \csname #2\endcsname{\@@tempa@@##3}%
        \expandafter\edef\csname current#2name\endcsname{\@currentlabelname}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\makeatother


\DefineTreeLevel{section}
\DefineTreeLevel[section]{subsection}
\DefineTreeLevel[subsection]{subsubsection}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\treesection{A1}
\treesubsection[B1]{B1}
\treesubsubsection[C1]{C1}
\treesubsection[B2]{B2}
\treesubsubsection[C2]{C2}
\treesubsubsection[C3]{C3}


\treesection{Z}
\treesubsection{B1}
\treesubsection{B2}
\treesubsubsection{C1}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution! Unfortunately it seems not to work with customizing the TOC title of the section. When I do `\treesubsubsection[B2]{B2}` and `\treesubsubsection[C1]{C1}` it shows `B2` and `C1` in the TOC however it also cuts the `A1` from `A1/B2/C1`'s section title in the body. Because section names can become quite large like this I would like to have only the leaf name in the TOC.

Comment: @a_guest: You would have the same trouble with your 'original' `\tree...` macros, woudn't you?

Comment: I don't see the point. Is the current section name deduced from what's in the TOC? And if so, can't we just store the current section name in another variable and retrieve it from there? Keeping the TOC and actual section names (those in the body) separated?

Comment: @a_guest: Are we talking about the first or the second version?

Comment: I am referring to your second version which uses `xparse`.

Comment: @a_guest: `\treesubsubsection[B2]{B2}` should give `B2` in the ToC and `A1/B2` in the body, right?

Comment: If you mean `\treesubsection[B2]{B2}` (only 1 `sub`), then yes. However `\treesubsubsection[C1]{C1}` gives `C1` in the TOC but `B2/C1` in the body.

Comment: @a_guest: Are you using the version with `\treechapter`?

Comment: Ah forgot to mention, I am using `\documentclass{article}` and removed `\DefineTreeLevel{chapter}` and used `\DefineTreeLevel{section}` instead. Is that a problem?

Comment: @a_guest: See the updated code with `article` only and the screen shot -- `\treesubsubsection[C1][C1]` gives `C1` in the ToC and `A1/B2/C1` in the body. And again, your original `\tree....` macros would not even distinguish between ToC and body ... so this ToC issue is actually a question change, in my point of view

Comment: Because you didn't use `\treesubsection[B2]{B2}`. If I want only `B2` (instead of `A1/B2`) in the TOC, then it won't work for `C1` in the body.

Comment: I don't think it's another question, it's just that my question is more specific. I not only want to refer to superior sections and thus obtaining a tree like section structure, I also want to be able to choose *any* TOC title for *any* section (as it is possible with "normal" sections). Using `section`, `subsection`, ... I can choose an arbitrary TOC title without invalidating the body's text. I would like to do the same using the tree structure.

Comment: @a_guest: See the next update at the bottom of my answer

Comment: Yes that now really solves my problem! Thank you a lot! I don't fully understand your solution, so if it's not a big effort could you maybe add some comments to your macro that explain what's happening?

Comment: @a_guest: I'll try later on (perhaps in a few days, I won't have access to LaTeX for the next few days), is that o.k?