# Get current “section” name without label that works in captions

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

My question basically the same as in question [Get current “section” name without label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75168). However I also need that this command also works in captions (which none of the linked solutions do).

I tries all three variants presented in [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75183/6945):

- `nameref` -> does not work at all (compile error)
- `titleref` -> does compile but the result is wrong
- `zref-titleref` -> does compile but the result is wrong (exactly like with titleref)

My adapted example looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titleref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\TR@currentTitle}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{My section name}
The name of the current section is: "\currentname{}".\\
It should be: "My section name".

\subsection{My subsection name}
The name of the current subsection is: "\currentname{}".\\
It should be: "My subsection name".

\begin{figure}
\caption{AAA "\currentname{}" BBB}
FIGURE
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The expected output for the figure caption was

`AAA "My subsection name" BBB`. However it is

`AAA "AAA "My subsection name" BBB" BBB`.

Is there anything I can do to make `\currentname{}` work also in captions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `titleref` package redefines the `\caption` command to also save its contents to `\TR@currentTitle`. That's why you get a repetition in your output.

You can deactivate the effect of `titleref` on `\caption` by doing:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\@caption\TR@old@caption}
\makeatother
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titleref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\TR@currentTitle}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\@caption\TR@old@caption}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{My section name}
The name of the current section is: "\currentname{}".\\
It should be: "My section name".

\subsection{My subsection name}
The name of the current subsection is: "\currentname{}".\\
It should be: "My subsection name".

\begin{figure}
\caption{AAA "\currentname{}" BBB}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```