Add the word "Supplementary" to tables and figures, in a cross-referenced file
Introduction.
I am cross-referencing tables and figures from a supplementary.tex file to a main.tex file, by using the xr package and the latexmkrc file (I copied and pasted the latexmkrc file from Cross referencing with the xr package in Overleaf). In other words, in the main.tex file, I need to "call" the references of figures and tables, which are defined in the supplementary.tex file. My MWE is the  following:
supplementary.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Tables}
\label{supp_table}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline material  & T [K] \\ \hline
    Sn               & 3,7   \\
    Pb               & 7,2   \\
    Al               & 1,2   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{My table.}
\label{my_table}
\end{table}

\section{Figures}
\label{supp_fig}
\begin{figure*}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure1/test_figure_latex1}
    \caption{Left}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure1/test_figure_latex2}
    \caption{Right}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{My figure.}
  \label{my_figure}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}


main.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xr}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{
\typeout{(#1)}
\@addtofilelist{#1}
\IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}\makeatother
\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{%
\externaldocument{#1}%
\addFileDependency{#1.tex}%
\addFileDependency{#1.aux}%
}
\myexternaldocument{supplementary}

\begin{document}

\noindent
In \Cref{supp_table} there is \Cref{my_table}.\\ \\
In \Cref{supp_fig} there is \Cref{my_figure}.

\end{document}


Question.
Once I am in the main.tex file, how can I automatically add the word "Supplementary" to the referenced figures and tables which are defined in the supplementary.tex file?
(in order to have the following names: "Supplementary Figure" and "Supplementary Table")
Desired Output.
My desired is to get automatically the names "Supplementary Figure" and "Supplementary Table" as outputs of the main file as follows:

In this moment, instead, I am adding "by hand" the word "Supplementary" to each figure and table which were defined in the supplementary file.
Note after the @gusbrs solution.
To people interested in this topic and in the method here kindly provided by @gusbrs: you might be also interested in How can I pass the name of a section from a tex file to another (with "zref-clever")? and in the @gusbrs great solution!

This looks somewhat familiar. Maybe search through the questions from the last 1 or 2 days in case the solution is already there.

Hi @Sam, if you mean this one "Creating a supplementary document with "Supplementary" prefixes (which are displayed in cross-referenced files)", it was mine, that I deleted and re-wrote in a better and clearer way... I did not find other similar questions that were asked in the last 1 or 2 days...  :-(

I don't remember the exact title, so could very well have been the deleted one. (In the future, maybe you could edit your question instead of reposting, on main meta, there are rumours that self-deleting questions can count towards a possible question ban)

Also, I tried to add the following command \renewcommand{\figurename}{Supplementary Figure} in the supplementary.tex file, hoping that the word "Supplementary" could be then displayed in the output of the main.tex file, but it did not work...

Ah, good to know about the consequences of the self-deletion of questions... I did not know..... Btw, it is 2-3 days I am trying to solve this issue, but I am not able to make it work.. :-(

Maybe you could increase the chances of getting an answer if you would provide a test document other people could actually compile and wouldn't get a bunch of image not found errors.

Thanks... Well.. I did already... I mean... I wrote the exact code I am using for both files supplementary.tex and main.tex, plus what I called as Desired Output with plain text. Basically, as I wrote, I want to display automatically - in the output of the main.tex, the additional word "Supplementary" with the words "Figure" and "Table". In order to get, automatically, the following names "Supplementary Figure" and "Supplementary Table"... I added the figure to increase the clarity... But I don't know which other text to add.. there is already all necessary to reproduce

Things like \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure1/test_figure_latex1} will prevent the document from compiling for everybody but you

Ahhhh, right! I forgot the figures!! Let me think what I can use to replace those dummy figures... Sorry

... and do you actually need all the complications from your file dependencies? Can you reproduce the problems with the default xr macros?

Have a look at the mwe package for replacement images everybody has

Yes, with the "mwe" package I could replace that \includegraphics with\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}, or something similar

About your question on the "complications from your file dependencies"... I think I did not understand what you mean and what I am supposed to do/try.... (my level is not great as the level of most of the people in this community :-))

This is how I'd go about this using zref-clever (you may be able to pull off a similar approach using cleveref, but I'm not sure it would be this straightforward to remap the reference types).
supplementary.tex:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\zcsetup{
  countertype={
    section=suppsection,
    table=supptable,
    figure=suppfigure,
    % And others you might need...
  },
}

\zcLanguageSetup{english}{
  type = suppsection ,
    Name-sg = Section ,
    name-sg = section ,
    Name-pl = Sections ,
    name-pl = sections ,
  type = suppfigure ,
    Name-sg = Figure ,
    name-sg = figure ,
    Name-pl = Figures ,
    name-pl = figures ,
  type = supptable ,
    Name-sg = Table ,
    name-sg = table ,
    Name-pl = Tables ,
    name-pl = tables ,
  % And others you might need...
}

\begin{document}

\section{Tables}
\label{supp_table}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline material  & T [K] \\ \hline
    Sn               & 3,7   \\
    Pb               & 7,2   \\
    Al               & 1,2   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{My table.}
\label{my_table}
\end{table}

\section{Figures}
\label{supp_fig}
\begin{figure*}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Left}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Right}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{My figure.}
  \label{my_figure}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}

main.tex:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\zexternaldocument{supplementary}

\zcLanguageSetup{english}{
  type = suppsection ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary section ,
    name-sg = supplementary section ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary sections ,
    name-pl = supplementary sections ,
  type = suppfigure ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary figure ,
    name-sg = supplementary figure ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary figures ,
    name-pl = supplementary figures ,
  type = supptable ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary table ,
    name-sg = supplementary table ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary tables ,
    name-pl = supplementary tables ,
  % And others you might need...
}

\begin{document}

\section{References}

In \zcref{supp_table} there is \zcref{my_table}.

In \zcref{supp_fig} there is \zcref{my_figure}.

\bigskip{}

Now, note why using a different reference type for the supplementary
references, even if it requires some work to setup, pays off.

You can get start of sentence, capitalization and other options to work
correctly, and without fuss.  \zcref[S]{supp_table} is a table in
supplementary.tex, for example.

You can mix references from supplementary and main and get proper results:
\zcref{main_table, my_table_main, main_fig, my_figure_main, supp_table,
  my_table, supp_fig, my_figure}.

Etc.

\section{Tables}
\label{main_table}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline material  & T [K] \\ \hline
    Sn               & 3,7   \\
    Pb               & 7,2   \\
    Al               & 1,2   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{My table.}
\label{my_table_main}
\end{table}

\section{Figures}
\label{main_fig}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image-b}
  \caption{My figure.}
  \label{my_figure_main}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



Chapeau! Oh gosh! I am so impressed!! And you can mix references just with \zcref!! I am really grateful!! :-) :-) I don't understand why none asked this question before, since it is quite common to call - from the main file - some tables and figures which are defined in the supplementary file :-)

@Ommo I don't think it is a usual to add such name prefix. I'd say, normally, this kind of thing would belong to the reference itself. E.g. as is done with an appendix, so that you'd have things like "section A", "figure "A.2" etc. such that the numbering makes things unambiguous by itself.

Ah ok, but I have seen the thing to add "supplementary" figure/table quite several times... Maybe it depends on the style of the journal... Maybe, just guessing.. Again, thanks a lot for your solution :-)

Just a small doubt (if too demanding I can open a new question)... In the supplementary.tex file I have a section called and labelled as follows \section{Tables} \label{supp_table}. Is there a simple way to "pass" the name of the section, i.e. "Table" in  this case, to the main.tex file, by using the command \zcref{supp_table}?  In that way, instead of displaying the text "supplementary section 1", I would just have the text "Table", i.e. the proper name of the section in the supplementary file.

For example, in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75168/get-current-section-name-without-label, I have tried to use the package \usepackage{zref-titleref}, and the solution proposed by @Heiko Oberdiek, to get the name of the section. The solution I refer is: \usepackage{zref-titleref} \makeatletter \newcommand*{\currentname}{\zref@getcurrent{title}}\makeatother. However, I am not able to pass that section name from the supplementary.tex file to the main.tex file (I mean by using  \currentname).

@Ommo That is very much a different question. Just ask a new one, linking to relevant other questions, and providing a MWE.  ;-)

Thanks, I do it immediately.... :-)

done: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/724924/how-can-i-pass-the-name-of-a-section-from-a-tex-file-to-another :-)
