How can I pass the name of a section from a tex file to another (with "zref-clever")?
Introduction & Question. This is a follow-up question to Add the word "Supplementary" to tables and figures, in a cross-referenced file.
Given the following MWE, which is based on the @gusbrs solution, how can I pass the name of a section from the supplementary.tex file to the main.tex file?
Minimal Working Example (MWE).
supplementary.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\zcsetup{
  countertype={
    section=suppsection,
    table=supptable,
    figure=suppfigure,
    % And others you might need...
  },
}

\zcLanguageSetup{english}{
  type = suppsection ,
    Name-sg = Section ,
    name-sg = section ,
    Name-pl = Sections ,
    name-pl = sections ,
  type = suppfigure ,
    Name-sg = Figure ,
    name-sg = figure ,
    Name-pl = Figures ,
    name-pl = figures ,
  type = supptable ,
    Name-sg = Table ,
    name-sg = table ,
    Name-pl = Tables ,
    name-pl = tables ,
  % And others you might need...
}

\begin{document}

\section{This is my section about tables}
\label{supp_table}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline material  & T [K] \\ \hline
    Sn               & 3,7   \\
    Pb               & 7,2   \\
    Al               & 1,2   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{My table.}
\label{my_table}
\end{table}

\end{document}


main.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\zexternaldocument{supplementary}

\zcLanguageSetup{english}{
  type = suppsection ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary section ,
    name-sg = supplementary section ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary sections ,
    name-pl = supplementary sections ,
  type = suppfigure ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary figure ,
    name-sg = supplementary figure ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary figures ,
    name-pl = supplementary figures ,
  type = supptable ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary table ,
    name-sg = supplementary table ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary tables ,
    name-pl = supplementary tables ,
  % And others you might need...
}
\begin{document}
In \zcref[S]{supp_table} there is \zcref[S]{my_table}.
\end{document}


Note: please remember that to make this MWE work you need the latexmkrc file that you can simply copy and paste from Cross referencing with the xr package in Overleaf.
Desired Output.
Insead of having the current output, i.e. ...

In Supplementary section 1 there is Supplementary table 1.

...I would like to have the following one:

In This is my section about tables there is Supplementary table 1.



Inspired from the solution proposed by @Heiko Oberdiek in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75168/get-current-section-name-without-label, I tried to use the package \usepackage{zref-titleref} to get the name of the section. The solution I refer is: \usepackage{zref-titleref} \makeatletter \newcommand*{\currentname}{\zref@getcurrent{title}}\makeatother. However, I am not able to pass that section name from the supplementary.tex file to the main.tex file (I mean by using \currentname).

You can just load zref-titleref (for the problem at hand, in supplementary.tex, but you probably want it in both files anyway). Then you refer to imported labels using the regular zref or zref-clever machinery. Nothing further or fancy is needed.
supplementary.tex:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{zref-titleref} % after (sub)caption
\usepackage{hyperref}

\zcsetup{
  countertype={
    section=suppsection,
    table=supptable,
    figure=suppfigure,
    % And others you might need...
  },
}

\zcLanguageSetup{english}{
  type = suppsection ,
    Name-sg = Section ,
    name-sg = section ,
    Name-pl = Sections ,
    name-pl = sections ,
  type = suppfigure ,
    Name-sg = Figure ,
    name-sg = figure ,
    Name-pl = Figures ,
    name-pl = figures ,
  type = supptable ,
    Name-sg = Table ,
    name-sg = table ,
    Name-pl = Tables ,
    name-pl = tables ,
  % And others you might need...
}

\begin{document}

\section{This is my section about tables}
\label{supp_table}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline material  & T [K] \\ \hline
    Sn               & 3,7   \\
    Pb               & 7,2   \\
    Al               & 1,2   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{My table.}
  \label{my_table}
\end{table}

\end{document}

main.tex:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\usepackage{zref-titleref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\zexternaldocument{supplementary}

\zcLanguageSetup{english}{
  type = suppsection ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary section ,
    name-sg = supplementary section ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary sections ,
    name-pl = supplementary sections ,
  type = suppfigure ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary figure ,
    name-sg = supplementary figure ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary figures ,
    name-pl = supplementary figures ,
  type = supptable ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary table ,
    name-sg = supplementary table ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary tables ,
    name-pl = supplementary tables ,
  % And others you might need...
}
\begin{document}

In \zcref[S]{supp_table} there is \zcref[S]{my_table}.
% Note, if you are using the S option everywhere like this, you may want to
% just set globally \zcsetup{cap,noabbrev} (or capfirst,noabbrevfirst, see the
% manual) in your preamble.  The S option is meant to markup references made
% at the start of sentences, so that they can be distinguished from mid
% sentences ones.

\texttt{zref} machinery in general just works: \par
\ztitleref{supp_table}, \ztitleref{my_table}\par
\zref[title]{supp_table}, \zref[title]{my_table}

Normally \verb|\zcref| is not really well suited for name/title refs, even if
it supports it.  But, since the default \texttt{zref} commands do not
hyperlink, you can get those from \texttt{zref-clever} tweaking the options a
little:\par
\zcref[ref=title,noname]{supp_table}\par
\zcref[ref=title,noname]{my_table}

\end{document}



Many thanks! You nailed it!! :-) Also, I was studying the documentation of the zref-clever package (trying to find a solution to the question), and I have just realised that you are the author of it! Cool :-)

@Ommo Yes. :-) Do enjoy!

@Ommo Looking closer at things, as far as I can tell, this was really just a load order issue. So I edited the answer and removed the workaround. The above now is then how things are expected to work.

Oh great, even easier to use (in my opinion), many many thanks :-)

Is there an option to always capitalise the references - in main.tex -, without using each time the option [S] in \zcref[S]? I went to the package docs https://ch.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/zref-clever/zref-clever-doc.pdf, but I am not sure if there is such an option and how to use it... I think it should be related to \zcsetup{(options)} (at page 6), but I am not sure what to put inside as options......

@Ommo Well, yes... And it's been written in the answer from the start. Please read it more carefully. And you can find more information in the manual: the relevant options are described in Section 7 (currently on p. 9). Anyway, you definitely don't want to be using S on each \zcref call like that, you can and should just set it up globally.

Thanks a lot :-) After checking page 9, I found the option cap=true. Therefore, in both file, i.e. supplementary.tex and in main.tex, I added that option through the following command: \zcsetup{cap=true}. In that way, \zcref automatically capitalized (the first letter of) all the references, without using [S] locally, for each reference. Thanks a lot!

Hi @gusbrs, I m trying to add cross-references for "subfigures" to the machinery of your solution (in particular to \zcLanguageSetup{english}{...}). I opened a new question, i.e. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/726210/how-can-i-pass-the-name-of-a-subfigure-from-a-tex-file-to-another-with-zref-cl. I am trying to navigating the "9 Reference format" of https://ch.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/zref-clever/zref-clever-doc.pdf, to find a solution, but nothing works :-( Do you have some suggestion? :-)
