Add the prefix "Supplementary" to a subfigure when cross-referencing it (with "zref-clever")
This is a follow-up question to

Add the word "Supplementary" to tables and figures, in a cross-referenced file, and
How can I pass the name of a section from a tex file to another (with "zref-clever")?

Given the following MWE, which is based on the @gusbrs solution, how can I add the prefix "Supplementary" to a subfigure when passing it from the supplementary.tex file to the main.tex file?
Minimal Working Example (MWE).
supplementary.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{zref-titleref} % after (sub)caption
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\zcsetup{cap,noabbrev,
  countertype={
    section=suppsection,
    table=supptable,
    figure=suppfigure,
    % And others you might need...
  },
}

\zcLanguageSetup{english}{
  type = suppsection ,
    Name-sg = Section ,
    name-sg = section ,
    Name-pl = Sections ,
    name-pl = sections ,
  type = suppfigure ,
    Name-sg = Figure ,
    name-sg = figure ,
    Name-pl = Figures ,
    name-pl = figures ,
  type = supptable ,
    Name-sg = Table ,
    name-sg = table ,
    Name-pl = Tables ,
    name-pl = tables ,
  % And others you might need...
}

\begin{document}

In \zcref{supp_figure}, which is called \zcref[ref=title,noname]{supp_figure}, we can read \zcref{my_figure_supp}, and its caption \zcref[ref=title,noname]{my_figure_supp}. Inside \zcref{my_figure_supp}, we have the following: \zcref{my_subfigure_a_supp,my_subfigure_b_supp}.

\section{Supplementary section about figures}
\label{supp_figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
    \centering
    \begin{subcaptiongroup}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (4.5cm,-0.5cm) {a};
        \phantomcaption\label{my_subfigure_a_supp}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \vspace{0.6cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (4.5cm,-0.5cm) {b};
        \phantomcaption\label{my_subfigure_b_supp}
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    \end{subcaptiongroup}
    \captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}
    \caption{
    Caption of my supplementary figure :-). Here we have subfigure \subref{my_subfigure_a_supp}, and subfigure
    \subref{my_subfigure_b_supp}.
    }
    \label{my_figure_supp}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


main.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\usepackage{zref-titleref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\zexternaldocument{supplementary}

\zcsetup{cap,noabbrev}
\zcLanguageSetup{english}{
  type = suppsection ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary section ,
    name-sg = supplementary section ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary sections ,
    name-pl = supplementary sections ,
  type = suppfigure ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary figure ,
    name-sg = supplementary figure ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary figures ,
    name-pl = supplementary figures ,
  type = supptable ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary table ,
    name-sg = supplementary table ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary tables ,
    name-pl = supplementary tables ,
  % And others you might need...
}
\begin{document}

In \zcref{supp_figure}, which is called \zcref[ref=title,noname]{supp_figure}, we can read \zcref{my_figure_supp}, and its caption \zcref[ref=title,noname]{my_figure_supp}. Inside \zcref{my_figure_supp}, we have the following: \zcref{my_subfigure_a_supp,my_subfigure_b_supp}.

\end{document}


Desired output
I would like to see the prefix "Supplementary" in front of the subfigures names when calling them in the main.tex. Something like or similar to this:


At page 13/38 of https://ch.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/zref-clever/zref-clever-doc.pdf, we can read "zref-clever provides default settings for the following reference types: part, chapter,
section, paragraph, appendix, subappendix, page, line, figure, table, item, footnote,
endnote, note, equation, theorem, lemma, corollary, proposition, definition, proof,
result, remark, example, algorithm, listing, exercise, and solution"....However, I cannot find anything like "subfigure"...... Any suggestion?

The only thing I am able to do is the following:
\zcref[ref=subfigure]{my_subfigure_a_supp}
and
\zcref[ref=subref]{my_subfigure_a_supp}```
which results in 
"_Inside **Supplementary figure 1**, we have the following: **Figure 1a** and **Figure a**_"

Well, this is all mostly missing data or packages in main.tex. When you are importing something from supplementary.tex to main.tex you need to make sure what you are bringing in makes sense in the latter. There are a number of problems:

The most troublesome there is that you are importing a caption (through zref-xr + zref-titleref) which contains a couple of \subref calls inside. This command is defined by subcaption, and you don't load the package in main.tex. That's why you get errors and an ugly output. Actually, zref-clever will need it too, since support for subcaption adds a property (subref) to the references in supplementary.tex, and unless subcaption is loaded in main.tex that property will not be recognized. So, first fix: load subcaption in main.tex.

Also, \subref uses the standard referencing system, and you didn't import the standard labels at all. So, if you want a caption from supplementary.tex containing \subrefs you need to import the \newlabels too, for which you need to load xr and use its \externaldocument. Alternatively, you could use a zref(-clever) command instead of \subref, your choice.

Furthermore, if you correct everything above, you still get a couple of hyperref warnings of "invalid page number". What's going on is that \subref is hyperlinked and when you call \zcref[ref=title] on that caption you are getting nested hyperlinks. This seems to "work" inside supplementary.tex, but it also appears enough to fool (zref-)xr. Either way, it is not a very good idea to be nesting them to start with, so you should probably use some unlinked (starred) reference command in that caption.

Finally, subcaption uses the subfigure counter for a subcaption inside a figure, and we haven't configured countertype for that counter in supplementary.tex (remember % And others you might need...). It's the same thing as for the others, but since zref-clever sets up this type in the subcaption compatibility module, and that is done at begindocument we have to take care of overriding that later than that.


supplementary.tex:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{zref-titleref} % after (sub)caption
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\zcsetup{cap,noabbrev,
  countertype={
    section=suppsection,
    table=supptable,
    figure=suppfigure,
    % And others you might need...
  },
}
% At begindocument since zref-clever sets this up in the compat module.
\AddToHook{begindocument}{\zcsetup{countertype={subfigure=suppfigure}}}

\zcLanguageSetup{english}{
  type = suppsection ,
    Name-sg = Section ,
    name-sg = section ,
    Name-pl = Sections ,
    name-pl = sections ,
  type = suppfigure ,
    Name-sg = Figure ,
    name-sg = figure ,
    Name-pl = Figures ,
    name-pl = figures ,
  type = supptable ,
    Name-sg = Table ,
    name-sg = table ,
    Name-pl = Tables ,
    name-pl = tables ,
  % And others you might need...
}

\begin{document}

In \zcref{supp_figure}, which is called \zcref[ref=title,noname]{supp_figure},
we can read \zcref{my_figure_supp}, and its caption
\zcref[ref=title,noname]{my_figure_supp}. Inside \zcref{my_figure_supp}, we
have the following: \zcref{my_subfigure_a_supp,my_subfigure_b_supp}.

\section{Supplementary section about figures}
\label{supp_figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
    \centering
    \begin{subcaptiongroup}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (4.5cm,-0.5cm) {a};
        \phantomcaption\label{my_subfigure_a_supp}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \vspace{0.6cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (4.5cm,-0.5cm) {b};
        \phantomcaption\label{my_subfigure_b_supp}
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    \end{subcaptiongroup}
    \captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}
    \caption{
    Caption of my supplementary figure :-). Here we have subfigure
    \subref*{my_subfigure_a_supp}, and subfigure
    \subref*{my_subfigure_b_supp}.
    }
    \label{my_figure_supp}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

main.tex:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{zref-titleref} % after (sub-)caption
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

% import \zref@newlabels as zref labels
\zexternaldocument{supplementary}
% import \newlabels as LaTeX labels
\zxrsetup{tozreflabel=false,toltxlabel=true}
\zexternaldocument*{supplementary}

\zcsetup{cap,noabbrev}
\zcLanguageSetup{english}{
  type = suppsection ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary section ,
    name-sg = supplementary section ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary sections ,
    name-pl = supplementary sections ,
  type = suppfigure ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary figure ,
    name-sg = supplementary figure ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary figures ,
    name-pl = supplementary figures ,
  type = supptable ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary table ,
    name-sg = supplementary table ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary tables ,
    name-pl = supplementary tables ,
  % And others you might need...
}
\begin{document}

In \zcref{supp_figure}, which is called \zcref[ref=title,noname]{supp_figure},
we can read \zcref{my_figure_supp}, and its caption
\zcref[ref=title,noname]{my_figure_supp}. Inside \zcref{my_figure_supp}, we
have the following: \zcref{my_subfigure_a_supp,my_subfigure_b_supp}.

\end{document}



Woww!! Thanks a lot!! Very cool answer :-)

I could not make it alone, I am really thankful!! :-)  Just a very small question... Did I understand correctly that the text "Supplementary figures 1a and 1b"  produced by \zcref{my_subfigure_a_supp,my_subfigure_b_supp} (in main.tex) cannot be entirely blue (i.e. hyperlinked).. indeed, only "1a" and "1b" are in blue... :-)

@Ommo Well, the only thing there about zref-clever was the countertype for subfigure, everything else was "xr setup issues"... As to your other question, that is just a standard \zcref call, if you want the name to be part of the link, just adjust the nameinlink option accordingly. Though you cannot have them "entirely in blue" since those are two separate references, not one. So "and" will always be out of the links.

Thanks for the explanation :-)  Yes, they are two different references, and yes, the "and" will be always out of the links... Ok, if I understood correctly I can do as \zcref[nameinlink]{...}... Thanks a lot again!! :-)

@Ommo Yes but nameinlink is the kind of option you'd usually set in your preamble, for consistency. Of course, you can do so just for that call, if you have a reason to do so.

Ah ok, well, then, probably better in the preamble (I guess as \usepackage[nameinlink]{zref-clever} ) Thanks!! :-)

@Ommo Well, almost, but no. ;-) zref-clever takes no load-time options, you need to use \zcsetup. Just add nameinlink to the call already there.

Ah ok, thanks a lot :-)

@Ommo I had one thing which was bothering me in this answer, I recalled zref-xr could also handle the standard labels as well, but I was still doing with xr. It turns out my vague memory was right, so I updated the answer to use only zref-xr. (Both work fine, of course, this is just a tiny bit "cleaner"). Bonus for your use case, zref-xr does not import citations so you don't have to worry about nocite.

Thanks a lot for your notification :-) I also like "cleaner" versions, when possible, thanks!
