# Write command so that commas appear properly

Tags: macros, spacing, punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\newcommand and spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17730/newcommand-and-spacing)

I want to write a command as a shortcut to insert text.

```
\newcommand{\bl}{$blah blah$}
```

When I write the command like this, "blah blah" runs into the next word. If I put a space after the second "$", then when I have

```
\bl,
```

I get

> blah blah ,

with a space before the comma. What's the proper way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `xspace` package,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\bl}{$blah blah$\xspace}
\begin{document}
\bl, \bl this is fine.
\end{document}
```