# Problem with spacing after abbreviation

Tags: spacing, acronyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\newcommand and spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17730/newcommand-and-spacing)
>   [No space following macro without argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25820/no-space-following-macro-without-argument)

I want to use `\newabbrev` for some abbreviations, but the spacing is off. With `\newabbrev`, I get spacing both before a new word and before a period. With a simple `\newcommand` it's the other way around. What do I do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abbrevs}
\newabbrev{\whp}{with high probability}
\newcommand{\whpcmd}{with high probability}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
The event occurs \whp by our previous argument. We get spacing, using \verb|\newabbrev|.
```

**Edit:** Specifically, why does the abbreviation get the space before the period? That doesn't seem to make sense.

```
The event occurs \whpcmd by our previous argument. No spacing (bad), Using \verb|\newcommand|.

The event occurs \whp. We get spacing (bad), using \verb|\newabbrev|.

The event occurs \whpcmd. No spacing, Using \verb|\newcommand|.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason why there's no spacing in the second case is because command eats all the following whitespace. You can protect it by empty braces: `... occurs \whpcmd{} by our ...`

Comment: You could use `\newcommand` and the `xspace` package, which will add a space only if the next character is *not* a punctuation mark. Have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15009/10119) (possible duplicate)

Comment: While having abbreviations for commonly used phrases may seem attractive, it's not very useful in the long run, as it makes the document unreadable, particularly when it's opened some time after it has been written. Look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17730/newcommand-and-spacing

Comment: Looks like I'm going to try to ween myself off the abbreviation like @egreg suggests, although that doesn't resolve the issue per se.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate. Other questions on the same topic do not refer to the `abbrevs` package. This package claims to intelligently detect when a space is required, without using `\xspace`.